# Unity Shader Graph Vertex Position not working as intended

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vertex-shader

I am attempting to create a shader using Shader Graph based on a tutorial that was originally made for Amplify Shader Editor.

[YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rd5sydSpRIo)

However, when connecting the last *ADD Node* to the *Vertex Position Node*, the material disappears from both the scene and the material preview in the bottom right corner. I have included images of my attempt for reference.

Here are the images:

- [image: FullGraph]
- Zoomed in:

  - [image: zoom1]
  - [image: zoom2]
  - [image: zoom3]

Finally when its disconnected the material appears again:
[disconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLMJk.png)

I believe the issue could be related to a switch from a Vector3 to a float, which would make the given vertex position invalid since it needs to be a Vector3. However, I am not sure how to fix this. Can someone please advise on how to resolve the disappearing material issue?